# Kendo MVC Grid Not Grouping When Using ClientGroupHeaderTemplate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have the following code to create my Kendo Grid but as you can see, it isn't grouping by CreatedDate correctly.  It works when I don't use `ClientGroupHeaderTemplate()`.

The question is, how can I use `.Group()` when using `ClientGroupHeaderTemplate()`?

[image]

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Models.MCMessageCenter>()
    .Name("myMessagesGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.Id);
        columns.Bound(c => c.MessageTitle);
        columns.Bound(c => c.CreatedDate)
            .ClientTemplate("#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(CreatedDate), 'yyyy-MM-dd') #")
            .ClientGroupHeaderTemplate("#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(value), 'yyyy-MM-dd') #");
    })
    .Scrollable()
    .Groupable()
    .Sortable()
    .Pageable(p => p
        .Refresh(true)
        .PageSizes(new int[] { 20, 50, 100 })
        .ButtonCount(5)
    )
    .DataSource(ds => ds
        .Ajax()
        .Group(g => g.Add(c => c.CreatedDate))
        .Sort(s => s.Add(c => c.CreatedDate).Descending())
        .Read(r => r.Action("MyMessagesRead", "Message"))
    )
)
```

I believe it's not working because the grouping functionality takes place on the server.  However, I don't want to convert the IQueryable to an IEnumerable since I the dataset could be large.  I would need a way of modifying the date before it gets sent to the view.

**Update:** Overriding the ToDataSourceResult method results in the following error:

[image]

Comment: Just in case, are you sure that the createdDate field has the same hour, minute and second for the records you want to be grouped?

Comment: No, the dates and times are different which is why I am trying to coalesce into the same day, so 1/1/2015 1:10am and 1/1/2015 12:00pm get grouped under the same grouping.  I would do this in the repository/controller; however, I am returning an IQueryable since I can't cast it to an IEnumerable for performance reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a model definition to your data source by adding the following line to your `DataSource()` definition:

```
.Model(mdl => mdl.Field(x => x.CreatedDate.Date))
```

Full example:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Models.MCMessageCenter>()
    .Name("myMessagesGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.Id);
        columns.Bound(c => c.MessageTitle);
        columns.Bound(c => c.CreatedDate)
            .ClientTemplate("#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(CreatedDate), 'yyyy-MM-dd') #")
            .ClientGroupHeaderTemplate("#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(value), 'yyyy-MM-dd') #");
    })
    .Scrollable()
    .Groupable()
    .Sortable()
    .Pageable(p => p
        .Refresh(true)
        .PageSizes(new int[] { 20, 50, 100 })
        .ButtonCount(5)
    )
    .DataSource(ds => ds
        .Ajax()
        .Model(mdl => mdl.Field(x => x.CreatedDate.Date))
        .Group(g => g.Add(c => c.CreatedDate))
        .Sort(s => s.Add(c => c.CreatedDate).Descending())
        .Read(r => r.Action("MyMessagesRead", "Message"))
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and `.Model(mdl => mdl.Field(x => x.CreatedDate.ToShortDateString()))` but it still produces the same unsatisfactory result.  I believe this is because the grouping is done on the server; so I would need a way to modify it before it gets sent to the view.

Comment: Try adding the `.Date` to the column definition as well: `columns.Bound(c => c.CreatedDate.Date)`

Comment: Result is different in that the grouping date is no longer formatted as yyy-MM-dd but still there is no grouping as would be expected; all groups contain only one item.